# Difference between two dimensional different flavours type array ? Advantages of these of two type

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I am trying to study `array` in depth. I tried so many multidimensional array but didn't understand

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        String [][] obj1 = new String [10][5];
        String [][] obj2 = new String [10][];

        System.out.println(obj1[1].length);
        System.out.println(obj2[1].length);
    }
}
```

In this example , I have tried two double dimensional array.

`String [][] obj1 = new String [10][5];` and `String [][] obj2 = new String [10][];`.

Now

`System.out.println(obj1[1].length);` gives the length `5` as a Output. Totally Cleared.

In Second sysout statement throws `NullPointerException`

`System.out.println(obj2[1].length);` Totally UnCleared. because i am not trying to access the member variables only want to get the length.

So, why `NullPointerException` Here ? Is there **really any advantage of Second type of array** declaration ??

Please explain in details, found several Sources but still Confused.

Thanks

Comment: Read up on jagged arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `String [][] obj2 = new String [10][];` you are initializing `obj2` to refer to an array of 10 `String[]` elements. The elements of the array are initialized to `null`, which is why `obj2[1].length` throws a `NullPointerException`.

This type of declaration allows you to assign arrays of different lengths in the 2D array.

For example :

```
obj2[0] = new String[5];
obj2[1] = new String[10];
```

while in

```
String [][] obj1 = new String [10][5];
```

all the inner arrays have the same length of 5, since here you are initializing `obj1` to refer to an array of 10 `String[]` elements, each of which is initialized to refer to an array of 5 `String` elements.

Comment: One confusion still resides that why length gives `nullPointer` It may reflect thi size of `0`.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap `obj2[1]` is null, so `obj2[1].length` gives `NullPointerException`, just like any attempt to dereference a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

> In Second sysout statement throws NullPointerException

Which you would expect as it hasn't been initialise.

> i am not trying to access the member variables only want to get the length.

You didn't create any such array or give it a length so this doesn't make sense.

> Is there really any advantage of Second type of array declaration ??

You might not want all the arrays to have the same length in which case you can set each one to whatever length you want.